# Has the compare/merge experience improved since Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm wondering which improvements have been made since Visual Studio 2010 with regards to check-in/merge functionality, based on TFS source control.

Examples:

- ability to identify unchanged files.
- quality of automatic merge.

Comment: yes (using Local Workspaces) and yes.

Comment: Is there anything else you're hoping for to learn?

Comment: While it's still a preview version, what about Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2012 and 2013 introduced a number of marked improvements:

- [My Work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx) (Visual Studio 2012/2013 Premium and Ultimate) offers a very handy suspend/resume option to quickly shelve local changes in order to work on something else (high prio incident, reviewing another developer's changes etc)
- [Pending Changes](http://chamindac.blogspot.nl/2013/09/tfs-2013-team-explorer-unlock-pending.html) screen has been revamped (opinions differ whether it's an improvement)
- [Local workspaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx), support for offline working, better detection of local changes, removal of the read-only-bit.
- [Improved merge experience](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/31/merge-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx)
- UI support for baseless merges

Visual Studio 2015 not much has changed, [but Microsoft is adding a few new features around TFVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/03/12/the-future-of-team-foundation-version-control.aspx).

> - We're building a new code search experience.  Though the private preview only supports Git, we will add TFVC support before it ships.
> - We're working on code review improvements, including things like support for iterative code reviews, a web experience, an improve VS experience with inline commenting, etc.  All of this will work for TFVC too.